# HttpContext.Current.Response.Write not working on IE

Tags: c#, iis, httpcontext

Im trying to capture an http and remove some element from it using javascript
its working on chrome but not working on IE.

```
void context_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext context = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context;
    if (context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Contains(@"/account/"))
    {        
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(@"<script type='text/javascript'> document.getElementById('swtch').style.display = 'none';</script>");        
    }
}
```

i tried:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();

HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(@"<script type='text/javascript'> document.getElementById('swtch').style.display = 'none';</script>"); 
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

It writes the script but also it clears entire html and the object i am looking for is not there anymore.

The site is running on IIS, i managed to debug it, it goes to the code but on the final result i dont see the script, i tried different script, still no luck

Answer (score 0):

I know my answer is so late, but maybe it can be helpful! 
You can try:

```
  obj.removeAttribute('dsplay');
```